# Understanding method build and input input_shape in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to understand a basic example in https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_researchers/ in particular:

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b


class MLP(keras.layers.Layer):
    """Simple stack of Linear layers."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.linear_1 = Linear(32)
        self.linear_2 = Linear(32)
        self.linear_3 = Linear(10)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.linear_1(inputs)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.linear_2(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return self.linear_3(x)

mlp = MLP()
y = mlp(tf.ones(shape=(3, 64)))
```

I think this is very basic questions but I do not find an explanation (maybe because I do not how to look for).

1-Why it is call the method **build** the first time the layer is call?

2-And if a tensor `tf.ones(shape=(3, 64))` is passed, why the **input_shape** in the method **build** is a TensorShape?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Build` is called when the object is created one time , input_shape because so often you dont know the input shape of your tensor in advance neither how much wight your layer needs, its pretty healthy to have it that way cuz the method `call` would be called everytime a forward propagation happpen so keras have it seperated that way

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, Why `Build`  is call? I mean, it is a special method, as __init__ , if so, where I can find more information? And about the input_shape, I understand the reason, but I do not understand how it is possible that if I pass a Tensor the inputs use in **build**, it is a TensorShape.